# Как достать адреса?

Tags: gmail

Как можно достать адреса всех ящиков, с которых приходили письма с одной и той же темой?
Хотелось бы экспортнуть их, скажем, в .csv  
Есть идеи как это реализовать?

Comment: Коннектится через POP/IMAP, получить всю почту и отобрать письма с определенной темой.

Comment: @ReinRaus, а без этого гемороя никак? Неужели в гугле нет нужного функционала?

Comment: Через веб-морду этого точно нельзя сделать, возможно смогут помочь почтовые программы вроде `The Bat`.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему всё проще. Создаёте фильтр по теме и навешиваете на все письма отобранные какой-то ярлычок уникальный. Идёте в [Google TakeOut](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout) и [выгружаете архив](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024195?hl=ru#gmail) только с таким ярлыком. Вуаля. Правда данные будут в формате MBOX, но зато они будут)

Answer (score 1):

Знаю как это можно по POP сделать, но его нужно сначала включить на Жимейле.

```
Connect to ssl://pop.gmail.com:995
> USER myname@gmail.com
> PASS mypassword
> STAT // получим кол-во сообщений
```

Теперь нужно в цикле выполнить команду `TOP` и как-то сохранить полученный результат:

```
> TOP <номер_сообщения> 0
```

(Здесь 0 — это параметр, определяющий, сколько строк самого письма вернет сервер; так как содержимое писем нам не нужно, пишем 0).

Когда цикл будет пройден и будет собран массив заголовков писем, можно будет с этим орудовать: выяснять в какой кодировке записаны поля `Subject`, преобразовывать их к одному виду. Те же операции сделать и с полем, в котором хранится адрес отправителя `From`.

Если хочешь, могу скинуть обертку для связи с POP-сервером на похапе.